# Solr inaccurate search result

Tags: search, solr, lucene, solrj

it seems to be an issue / bad configuration in my solr index.

In detail when I perform a search by using some words in my query the solr result is ok, it returns me 50 entries.

Let me show an example :

***Example 1)***

```
url = http://mydomain:8983/solr/mycore/select?q=walk%20in%20the%20city
query = walk in the city
results = 231373, 231372, 231454, ....
```

Unfortunately when I use a single word in my query the solr result is "truncated"

Let me show some examples :

***Example 2)***

```
url = http://mydomain:8983/solr/mycore/select?q=Walk
query = Walk
results = 231373, 231372
```

***Example 3)***

```
url = http://mydomain:8983/solr/mycore/select?q=city
query = city
results = 231373, 231372
```

As you can see "Walk" and "city" words are inside my first query set.
The results in examples 2/3 are the same.

I'm a beginner in using solr, probably I perform some mistakes in solr configuration.
What I have to check first in order to optimize the query?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.
Sergio

Comment: what is the query field? what is the field type applied to it?

Comment: In the first case, if the `q.op` is set to OR - you're effectively searching for any documents with _either_ `walk`, `in`, `the` or `city`. It follows that this will give far more hits than just one of the terms alone, especially the two terms that are the least common (`walk` and `city`). A stop word filter will remove `in` and `the` if active, but I'm guessing you don't have that. In addition for specific field configurations, case will be important.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to add `debugQuery=true` to your query and look at the `debug` node in the result. Under `debug` in particular look at the `parsedquery` to see what Solr is doing with your query, like what fields it's searching and whether it is using AND or OR between expressions (e.g. `+fieldName` means AND).

Also, under the `debug` there is an `explain` node that contains the documents that were found and *why* they were found. That should help you pin point why those records were returned. The `explain` output is pretty convoluted, but there is a lot of useful information there for this kind of issues.

(I realize this is not quite an answer to your question, but it's too long for a comment.)

Comment: At the moment I solved by changing the configuration of the _select_ request handler. In detail I jump from **<str name="qf">categoria^30 caratteristiche_txt_multi titolo^20 taglie_str^20 colori_str contenuto codice_a^100 codice_s^100</str>** to **<str name="qf">contenuto categoria caratteristiche_txt_multi marchio_txt titolo codice_s</str>** removed weight and changed the position of _contenuto_ field. It seems to be good for the search. I'll keep on investigate for best solution. Thank you for the response!